# How the following function can be used or called?

Tags: c, gcc

I have written the following program, I wanted to know how it could be used. Or is this the correct way to use the `squeeze(char s[z], int c)` in the main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s[], int c)
{
   int i, j;

   for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    s[j] = '\0';

}

int main()
{
    squeeze("catalonia", 'c');

}
```

ps: it returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` on execution.

Feel free to offer corrections.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick, the concept of "return" has a very specific meaning in programming and CS. "Segmentation fault" is a signal that may be triggered, sent or received. But typically seldom used as return value.

Answer (score 2):

The function is modifying the input string in place, so it cannot be called with string literal as a parameter for two reasons:

1. String literals are read-only (that is, an attempt to modify them lead to undefined behavior) - and this is the reason for the SEGFAULT you are seeing.
2. The result of the function won't be accessible because you don't have any "handle" to it.

The solution is to provide the input as a modifiable array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s[], int c)
{
   int i, j;

   for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        if (s[i] != c)
            s[j++] = s[i];
    s[j] = '\0';

}

int main()
{
    char input[] = "catalonia";
    squeeze(input, 'c');

    // Print the result
    printf("%s\n", input);
}
```